# Location of value, service, form objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app and I'm more and more refactoring my app by using value objects, service objects, form objects, etc. Currently, most of them are stored in the "lib" folder of the Rails app, but somehow that feels "far away" from the core app files.

I am wondering what the best practice is for the location these objects in a Rails app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactoring, cleaning-up your models and encapsulating logic in "value objects, service objects, form objects" is a way to go! As for your question about where to store these objects, nothing stops you from creating additional directories under 'app' directory.

By default Rails autoloads these directories, so you don't have to manage these.

Here is an example dir structure of one of my projects, under 'app' directory:

```
assets
cells
charts
controllers
decorators
form_objects
helpers
help_pages
inputs
mailers
models
modules
queries
renderers
resolvers
services
validators
views
widgets
```

The above list is by no means a pattern to follow, but I hope the list will inspire your refactoring efforts :)

Comment: Great, so there's no holding back in organizing my new objects, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I created a `value_objects` directory inside the `models` folder - just one of the ways to do it.